# Flutter firebase cloud function typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a cloud function for the user to get notification.
I have a Task model in which the user specifies a task and writes the email id of the other user he assigns the task to.
[image]

When the above task is added it should send the notification to the user specified in field 'Taskgivento'

My user model is as follows
[image]
I have a users models having data of a user and a subcollection in it saving the fcm in token subcollection .the id of the subcollection is the fcm token.

My cloud function

```
export const sendToDevice = functions.firestore
  .document('Task/{TaskId}')
  .onCreate(async snapshot => {

   const Taskdata=snapshot.data()

   const querySnapshot = await db
      .collection('users')
      .doc('HMPibf2dkdUPyPiDvOE80IpOsgf1')
      .collection('tokens')
      .get();

    const tokens = querySnapshot.docs.map(snap => snap.id);

    const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'New Order!',
        body: 'new notification',
        icon: 'your-icon-url',
        click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
      }
    };

    return fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
  });
```

in the const queryshot i am trying to filter the user model to get thee fcm token such that the the uid it notifies the Taskgiven to emailid.

The above function works.
I have manually written the uid in the above model .
I need it to search the database and fill the uid of the email of taskgivento.
How should i procceed
I have tried writing where('email','=','Taskdata.Taskgivento') like we do in dart but of no use. it is giving an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
export const sendToDevice = functions.firestore
    .document('Task/{TaskId}')
    .onCreate(async snapshot => {

        const Taskdata = snapshot.data()
        const email = Taskdata.Taskgivento;

        const userQuerySnapshot = await db
            .collection('users')
            .where('email', '==', email)
            .get();

        const userDocSnapshot = userQuerySnapshot.docs[0]; // Assumption: there is only ONE user with this email
        const userDocRef = userDocSnapshot.ref;

        const tokensQuerySnapshot = await userDocRef.collection('tokens').get();

        const tokens = tokensQuerySnapshot.docs.map(snap => snap.id);

        const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'New Order!',
                body: 'new notification',
                icon: 'your-icon-url',
                click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
            }
        };

        await fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
        return null;

    });
```

---

You need to:

1. Get the user Document. Note the syntax of `where('email', '==', email)` with `==`.
2. Get the [`DocumentReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html) of this Document, and based on this Reference, query the `tokens` subcollection.